# ASP.NET MVC3 datetime format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have MVC3 project with Entity.
I have Data Annotation on DateTime property with `DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}")`

Controller with method which has entity as argument and calling view with same entity object, which displaying its date property.

So, I open browser and enter link `http://site/entity/method?dateproperty=01/09/2012 01:02:03` (1 September 2012) and it displays `09/01/2012 01:02:03` (9 January 2012).

In view I'm using `DisplayFor` it's displaying like `dd/MM/yyyy` as I have a set DisplayFormat.

Problem is that it's reading like `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`, any solution?

P.S. I have tried `globalization` in web.config `&lt;sysmte.web&gt;` but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is that you haven't specified `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` in your attribute, so it's *parsing* using the default format, but *formatting* with the format you're specifying.

I'm not an MVC dev by any means, but if you want the same format to be used in both directions, I believe you can just change your attribute to:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
               DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
```

Note that I've changed `hh` to `HH`, as I suspect you want a 24-hour format. I'd actually suggest using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (ISO-8601) as a less ambiguous format for the URL parameter - with a more user-centric *display* format, of course.

Comment: Thanks.
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" really helped me. Thank you again :)